# using <form> within <foreach> a few time

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jstl

I'm pretty new to Spring and I'm trying to use Spring MVC + JSP + JSTL.  My goal is to make JSP which containts list of Users and allow to edit each User  separately from others. So I think I should use separate `<form>` tag and separate `<sumbit>` button for every User in the list and my JSP looks like:

```
<c:forEach items="${userList}" var="currentUser" varStatus="index">
        <form:form method="post" action = "edit" commandName="userList[${index}]">
        <tr>
            <td><form:input path = "userList[${index}].login" value = "${currentUser.login}" /></td>
            <td><form:input path = "userList[${index}].password" value = "${currentUser.password}" /></td>
            <td><form:input path = "userList[${index}].smtpServer" value = "${currentUser.smtpServer}" /></td>
            <td><form:input path = "userList[${index}].popServer" value = "${currentUser.popServer}" /></td>
                <form:hidden path="userList[${index}].id" value=""/>
            <td>
                <a href="delete/${user.id}"><spring:message code="label.delete" /></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
           <input type="submit" value = "edit"> 
        </form:form>
    </c:forEach>
```

the idea is to have an opportunity to edit each user separately by pressing the button "edit". Ofcourse this code doesn't work. It gives me an exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain
>   target object for bean name 'userList[javax' available as request
>   attribute

I'm really totally noob at Spring and at web-programming too. I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont understant why you are using `userList[${index}]` since you have a different form for each user. Anyway your code isnt right at this line `commandName="userList[${index}]"`

Here is what I suggest :

```
<c:forEach items="${userList}" var="currentUser" varStatus="index">
    <form:form method="post" action = "edit" commandName="user">
    <tr>
        <td><form:input path = "login" value = "${currentUser.login}" /></td>
        <td><form:input path = "password" value = "${currentUser.password}" /></td>
        <td><form:input path = "smtpServer" value = "${currentUser.smtpServer}" /></td>
        <td><form:input path = "popServer" value = "${currentUser.popServer}" /></td>
            <form:hidden path="id" value=""/>
        <td>
            <a href="delete/${user.id}"><spring:message code="label.delete" /></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
       <input type="submit" value = "edit"> 
    </form:form>
</c:forEach>
```

According that your user class is user.

Comment: That's because I'm noob :) Thanks! You are definetely right! So not it all works! Thank you :)

Answer (score 5):

Your use of ${index} isn't what you think. To get the index of the current item you must append ".index" to your varStatus variable... in your case it would be ${index.index}.  For clarity, consider naming your varStatus something other than index...

```
<c:forEach items="${userList}" var="currentUser" varStatus="uStatus">
    <form:form method="post" action = "edit" commandName="userList">
    <tr>
        <td><form:input path = "userList[${uStatus.index}].login" value = "${currentUser.login}" /></td>
        <td><form:input path = "userList[${uStatus.index}].password" value = "${currentUser.password}" /></td>
        <td><form:input path = "userList[${uStatus.index}].smtpServer" value = "${currentUser.smtpServer}" /></td>
        <td><form:input path = "userList[${uStatus.index}].popServer" value = "${currentUser.popServer}" /></td>
            <form:hidden path="userList[${uStatus.index}].id" value=""/>
        <td>
            <a href="delete/${currentUser.id}"><spring:message code="label.delete" /></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
       <input type="submit" value = "edit"> 
    </form:form>
</c:forEach>
```

Keep in mind, this doesn't make sense using a different form for each user... but say you wanted to edit any/all of your users at once....

```
<form:form method="post" action = "edit" commandName="userList">
    <c:forEach items="${userList}" var="currentUser" varStatus="uStatus">

    <tr>
        <td><form:input path = "userList[${uStatus.index}].login" value = "${currentUser.login}" /></td>
        <td><form:input path = "userList[${uStatus.index}].password" value = "${currentUser.password}" /></td>
        <td><form:input path = "userList[${uStatus.index}].smtpServer" value = "${currentUser.smtpServer}" /></td>
        <td><form:input path = "userList[${uStatus.index}].popServer" value = "${currentUser.popServer}" /></td>
            <form:hidden path="userList[${uStatus.index}].id" value=""/>
        <td>
            <a href="delete/${currentUser.id}"><spring:message code="label.delete" /></a>
        </td>
    </tr>

    </c:forEach>
    <input type="submit" value = "edit"> 
</form:form>
```